# Why is WordPress placing "text/rocketscript" instead of "text/javascript" when using wp_register_script()?

Tags: wordpress

I inserted the following code in a **WordPress plugin:**

```
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js");
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

The following is echoed to the **browser:**

```
<script type='text/rocketscript' data-rocketsrc='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I don't know what is happening. Perhaps **`wp_register_script()`** is supposed to work in this way. I also **tested** if any jQuery code worked on the **client side** but it didn't.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably one of wordpress plugins is using `CloudFlare`.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-

Try disabling all the plugins and re-enabling them one by one to find out which one is causing this issue. It's not a problem actually.

Comment: Yes, rocketscript is Cloudflare's technology.

Comment: As far as i know CloudFlare is not coming with wordpress by default. You should be able to disable RocketScript somehow (probably by disabling a plugin or from a config page). Maybe you should try things like CTRL+F5 or clearing the browser cache. But i can assure you don't have that issue with a clean wordpress installation.

Answer (score 53):

It is easy to fix.

You must change the following tag: `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

add: `data-cfasync="false"`

example:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: See also: http://cloudflare.tenderapp.com/kb/cloudflare-website-optimization-and-speed-features/how-can-i-have-rocket-loader-ignore-my-scripts-in-automatic-mode

Comment: Same info as last comment, but linking on their new support system: https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22063443-how-can-i-have-rocket-loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-automatic-mode

Comment: nice sharing @Frank but can you help me how can i add    data-cfasync="false" to wp_enqueue_script() function.

Comment: @WaheedUrRehman see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/webaware/8949605) for the approach I had to take. NB: `data-async="false"` must come before the `src` attribute!

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Saved my day.

Comment: As of 2017, This is still the best answer !

Answer (score 4):

Rocket Loader is not included in any WordPress plugins. You would have to disable Rocket Loader by going to: settings->CloudFlare settings (Performance Settings)->Rocket Loader->Toggle Off (this feature is optional and has to be turned on).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue with

**WP Rocket** plugin which was adding  `type='text/rocketscript'` to the script tags.

Fixed it by adding

`data-cfasync="false"`

to the script tags.