# Slideshow won't load in Safari

Tags: javascript, wordpress, safari

I'm running Wordpress 3.6. Some days ago, I ran into a weird problem: Suddenly Safari won't load any of my JavaScripts, meaning that my homepage flex slider slideshow doesn't show, Portfolio Slideshow Pro doesn't work, and Contact Form 7 doesn't have that spinner once you press "Send". I've tested and confirmed this problem on 4 Macs.

This problem, however, is not present at all in any other major browser, including IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and iPhone/iPad. Here, it works perfectly fine.

Here's my site: www.fotokasper.com

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by the looks of it - wordpress is adding `<script type='text/rocketscript'>` probably from registering the script or a plugin.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681032/why-is-wordpress-placing-text-rocketscript-instead-of-text-javascript-when-u) and maybe this will fix it