# javascript is saying function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudflare

http://puu.sh/4JtJ9.png

I have a button that calls "createURL()", yet all of the sudden my code is saying, "createURL() undefined" whenever I press the button, I'm using cloudflare and maybe that's the issue, it was working perfectly fine until I updated jquery, now it keeps telling me my function is undefined, has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: It was working find until you broke the code (it has nothing to do with jQuery versions) - find out where.

Comment: the code is fine, it's just that type="text/javascript" gets changed to type="text/rocketscript" and I have no idea what it is, i've disabled all cloudflare plugins and it still happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681032/why-is-wordpress-placing-text-rocketscript-instead-of-text-javascript-when-u

Comment: @user1925957 Still unrelated to jQuery (but perhaps not the *usage* of such in the given environment). Re-examine the statement "it was working perfectly fine until I updated jquery".

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Rocket Loader in your performance settings. The clue is right here:

"type="text/rocketscript"