# "Missing analytics.js script" in google tag assistant

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Please, help me to solve this issue:

[image]

Google Tag assistant says that "Missing analytics.js script", but it present in code. What is wrong?

This issue is on page https://xn--b1agjaalfq5am6i.su/eglo-89203-lyustry.html

Adding  type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" to SCRIPT tag has no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics Missing analytics.js script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209156/google-analytics-missing-analytics-js-script)

Comment: This topic was not helped me.

Comment: You are including the debug version of the script, which is at least unusual. Also your image misses the actual pageview tracking call, does that follow anywhere later on the page ?

Comment: Thanks! I was change analytics_debug.js to analytics.js and Google Tag assistant see it now. Yes, I call pageview later.

Comment: Have you included an additional reference to anlytics script on your page,as it is configured by default by GTM

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who will face with the same issue: Google Tag assistant does not understand, when you use analytics_debug.js instead of analytics.js. (thanks to  Eike Pierstorff)