# jQuery .insertAfter not working, trying to move element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have tried the following jQuery code to move a `<select>` element (**that I can only see within the DOM**) after a `<form>` element but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('[id^=lc_currency]').insertAfter('[id^=lc_change]');
</script>
```

I have also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('select[id^=lc_currency]').insertAfter('form[id^=lc_change]');
</script>
```

Any coding suggestions? I am using a wildcard selector because on every page the ID changes, 1c_currency1, 1c_currency2, etc.

Live site is at http://thehungrygeek.com/2015/11/17/australia-dairy-company/

I want to move specifically a select dropdown box, from one place to another on a webpage. Unfortunately the element code is only located in the DOM.

[image]

This select dropdown box is located at the bottom of the page at http://thehungrygeek.com/2015/11/17/australia-dairy-company/

The code, only located in the DOM, is as follows:

```
<select style="width:200px" name="lc_currency1" id="lc_currency1" onchange="localCurrencyChange('SGD',lcValues1,1)">...</select>
```

The select dropdown box is supposed to be moved here:

[image]

The relevant code at the area is as follows:

```
<form name="lc_change1" id="lc_change1" action="http://thehungrygeek.com/2015/11/17/australia-dairy-company/" method="post"> 
Show currencies in
<noscript>[Please enable JavaScript to change the currency used on this page]</noscript> 
<br>
<small>Powered by LocalCurrency. Rates from <a href="http://finance.yahoo.com" title="Visit Yahoo! Finance" target="_blank">Yahoo! Finance</a></small>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your id strings should be inside quote , Try this

```
$(function(){
    jQuery("select[id^='lc_currency']").insertAfter("form[id^='lc_change']");
});
```

Edit:

Try to move the select element after 1 sec after window load. this might works for you as your select element coming from javascript code.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){    
      jQuery("form[id^='lc_change']").prepend( "select[id^='lc_currency']");
   },1000);
});
```

Comment: I did try that and it did not work - also not the optimum solution as I require wildcard selectors

Comment: Does not work, probably an issue because the code is only found in the DOM, the quotations do not affect it, code is live now

Comment: @DavidZ please confirm if your select drop down is coming dynamically using some javascript.

Comment: the .prepend code is not working either - the select drop down is coming down from an installed Wordpress plugin, which is from some javascript, you can find the full code here, ctrl-f for localcurrency http://thehungrygeek.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_c68e4e2d017800dc4bb8142d4b35278f.js

Comment: @DavidZ this script is creating the select element, so you need to fire your code after the script adds the select element .

Comment: Ah that makes sense, unfortunately that won't be easy as I'm working with a Wordpress child theme. I'll try and figure out something to put on the functions.php

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the code work if it is placed before the script? I've seen an implementation before on another issue that I had:

`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('body').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
    var $tmp = jQuery(e.target).find(".shareaholic-share-button-container, .share-button-counter");
    if($tmp.length){
        $tmp.css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }
});
</script>`

That was for inserting a css class into an element

Comment: @DavidZ your currency select box loading before window load event fires, Use my updated code where I've fired the script on window load event. I think you don't need to add callback for 'DOMSubtreeModified' event , adding callback for 'DOMSubtreeModified' event will make your app very slow

Comment: Alright I've solved it by using the Wordpress functions.php to call the script at the end of the footer. As to which script worked well since I did that step 90% of the scripts suggested on this page would probably have worked. I think you had the closest answer to it without using that functions.php hack, thank you very much for the help and I'm giving you the check mark

Answer (score 1):

**1st:** Be sure you include jquery

**2nd:** Wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here   
});
```

**3rd:** Try to use `.each()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('select[id^=lc_currency]').each(function(){
          var getformId = $(this).attr('id').replace('currency','change');
          //alert(getformId);
          $(this).insertAfter('form#'+ getformId);
     });
 });
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8ocy7ngs/)

Comment: the issue might be that the relevant code targeted is implemented in the DOM, and thus not working - if you want to use jsfiddle my own solutions in the question that I said that I tried do work there

Comment: @David What does "implemented in the DOM" even mean?

Comment: `<select style="width:200px" name="lc_currency1" id="lc_currency1" onchange="localCurrencyChange('SGD',lcValues1,1)">...</select>` can't be seen in the regular 'view source', code is present within DOM - well I have no idea why it isn't working then

Comment: @DavidZ please copy/paste my 3rd step in my answer in your code and let me see it live

Comment: the 3rd answer code has been there live since you put it up 20+mins ago, and its still there. obviously I had to change the $ signs to jQuery, safe mode issues

Comment: @DavidZ Ok just to check...please alert(getformId)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Please let me know what code you want changed

Comment: I updated my answer with //alert(getformId);  just uncomment it  and let me see the alert in your website  ... I meant remove //   to be just  alert(getformId);

Comment: done, its possible that I may have to move the jQuery code right to the bottom of the site, but its quite difficult as I'm using a Wordpress child theme

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots you added, it seems like you want to insert the select inside the form, not after, this is what I used:

```
jQuery('[id^=lc_currency]').insertAfter('[id^=lc_change] noscript');
```

Comment: thanks, you are right... unfortunately I can't get any of the code to work, the box still stays in the original position

Comment: When do you try to move the select?

Comment: You can have a look at the page live, the code is there but the select button does not move

Comment: I noticed that instead if text/javascript you have text/rocketscript. Here is a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681032/why-is-wordpress-placing-text-rocketscript-instead-of-text-javascript-when-u

Comment: rocketscript is an implementation by Rocket Loader on Cloudflare, it does not affect how jQuery functions on my site - I have many other jQuery scripts and tweaks working fine, issue is specific to this particular plugin