# Script is displaying text on both occasions

Tags: javascript, adblock, rocketscript

I'm trying to display text when a user is using adblock; I am using the following script;

**ads.js**

```
<script>var canRunAds = true;</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<script data-rocketsrc="ads.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script type="text/rocketscript">
  if( window.canRunAds === undefined ){
    var x = "Adblock is enabled, Please disabled to continue.";
    document.write (x);
  }
</script>
```

However the problem I've been having is that the text is being displayed when the variable is defined and when its not defined.

Comment: try using `typeof window.canRunAdds === 'undefined')`

Comment: `if (typeof window.canRunAdds === 'undefined'){` would I use it like this? @Jacques

Comment: @LewisDay If you set `window.canRunAds` to `true` in `ads.js`, what result does that give?

Comment: @JamesMonger it would display nothing; so if the `window.canRunAds` is undefined i would want it to display the text and if it is defined as true to display nothing

Comment: @JamesMonger, yes, that's how you'd use it. Also, you may just want to check that canRunAdds is not true. so do `if (canRunAdds !== true) // do stuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ads.js`, set `window.canRunAds`. You'll also need to use `typeof` to check for `undefined`.

**ads.js**

```
window.canRunAds = true;
```

**index.php**

```
<script src="/ads/ads.js"></script>
<script>
  if (typeof window.canRunAds === 'undefined') {
    var x = "Adblock is enabled, Please disabled to continue.";
    document.write (x);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Notice

*In case it wasn't clear, the first inline `<script>` in each of these examples should be replaced with `<script src="/ads/ads.js"></script>` in order to work. I just can't do that here.*

### tl;dr

On the website, your `ads.js` file is loaded asynchronously using `data-rocketsrc="ads.js"`. Replace this with `src="ads.js"` to load it synchronously before the next inline script executes. Your page (omitting the `CloudFlare`) should look like this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Adblock</title>
  <script src="ads.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    if (typeof canRunAds === 'undefined') {
      document.write('canRunAds is being blocked<br/>');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the content of `https://flamingocams.com/ads/ads.js` should be:

```
var canRunAds = true;
```

Currently it has the contents:

```
<script>var canRunAds=true;</script>
```

I will admit I'm no expert in rocketscript, but my guess is that the running context of the script using that preprocessor is not `window`. Run it as regular JavaScript to guarantee synchronous execution in the `window` context.

### Answer

Simply use `typeof canRunAds === 'undefined'`. There is no need to use `window.canRunAds`, since `typeof` suppresses any possible `ReferenceError` when checking an undeclared variable, even in `strict mode`:

```html
<script>
  'use strict';
  var canRunAds = true;
  // to demonstrate the conditional `if` works
  // var someOtherFlag = true;
</script>

<script>
  'use strict';

  if (typeof canRunAds === 'undefined') {
    document.write('canRunAds is being blocked<br/>');
  }
  
  if (typeof someOtherFlag === 'undefined') {
    document.write('someOtherFlag is being blocked<br/>');
  }
</script>
```

However, it's generally a more common practice to have an element on the page that's conditionally visible based on CSS like this:

```css
p.adblock-warning {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

body.adblock p.adblock-warning {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<script>
  // assume this couldn't run
  // var canRunAds = true;
</script>

<script>
  if (typeof canRunAds === 'undefined') {
    document.body.classList.add('adblock');
  }
</script>

<p class="adblock-warning">Adblock is enabled, Please disabled to continue.</p>
```

Comment: @LewisDay Do they work when you run them here? They work for me. Please be more specific about how they don't work. I made the script inline since there is no option to create external scripts on the fly in stack snippets. The first script in each example should be replaced with `<script src="/ads/ads.js"></script>` when you reproduce them on your server.

Comment: give me to seconds i will provide you with a link; neither of them work when run

Comment: @LewisDay your `ads.js` file is written as HTML, not JavaScript. The content should be `var canRunAds=true;`, not `<script>var canRunAds=true;</script>`!

Comment: I have amended this issue and still no luck; I really do appreciate the help. And i can feel your struggle ahah

Comment: @LewisDay I think I've addressed everything now.

Comment: @LewisDay also, if you want to continue using rocketscript, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10611827/1541563). Again, I'm not an expert on it, but in this use-case I see no point in using rocketscript.

Answer (score -1):

As Jacques already pointed out, use the `typeof` operator when checking for undefined variables. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof.

In your code, one would check window.canRunAds with

```
typeof(window.canRunAds) === 'undefined'
```

because we can be sure, that the parent object **window** definitely is defined in your context. If it would be an object of which we do not know, first check for typeof(window) === 'undefined' to not getting an error.

Cheers!